# Search Data in Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to search data in my DataGridView to show only rows with selected text in textbox, but when I type it completely removes the Data. I took my code example on MSDN : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Search-Data-From-Database-f2cb5d53

here is my code:

```
     private void txtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        DataView DV = new DataView(datatable);
        DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtbox.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DV; 
     }
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Note: I am not using SQL, only C#

Whole thing: namespace CsvFileTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int MaxColumns = 64;
        protected string FileName;
        protected bool Modified;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeGrid();
        ClearFile();
    }

    private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SaveIfModified())
            ClearFile();
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SaveIfModified())
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                ReadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileName != null)
            WriteFile(FileName);
        else
            saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
    }

    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = FileName;
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            WriteFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SaveIfModified())
            Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// //////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// </summary>

    private void InitializeGrid()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= MaxColumns; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(
                String.Format("Column{0}", i),
                String.Format("Column {0}", i));
        }
    }

    private void ClearFile()
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        FileName = null;
        Modified = false;
    }

    private bool ReadFile(string filename)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
            //dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            List<string> columns = new List<string>();
            using (var reader = new CsvFileReader(filename))
            {
                while (reader.ReadRow(columns))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(columns.ToArray());
                }
            }
            FileName = filename;
            Modified = false;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error reading from {0}.\r\n\r\n{1}", filename, ex.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool WriteFile(string filename)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
            // Like Excel, we'll get the highest column number used,
            // and then write out that many columns for every row
            int numColumns = GetMaxColumnUsed();
            using (var writer = new CsvFileWriter(filename))
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (!row.IsNewRow)
                    {
                        List<string> columns = new List<string>();
                        for (int col = 0; col < numColumns; col++)
                            columns.Add((string)row.Cells[col].Value ?? String.Empty);
                        writer.WriteRow(columns);
                    }
                }
            }
            FileName = filename;
            Modified = false;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error writing to {0}.\r\n\r\n{1}", filename, ex.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Determines the maximum column number used in the grid
    private int GetMaxColumnUsed()
    {
        int maxColumnUsed = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (!row.IsNewRow)
            {
                for (int col = row.Cells.Count - 1; col >= 0; col--)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[col].Value != null)
                    {
                        if (maxColumnUsed < (col + 1))
                            maxColumnUsed = (col + 1);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return maxColumnUsed;
    }

    private bool SaveIfModified()
    {
        if (!Modified)
            return true;

        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("The current file has changed. Save changes?", "Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (FileName != null)
            {
                return WriteFile(FileName);
            }
            else
            {
                saveFileDialog1.FileName = FileName;
                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                    return WriteFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else // DialogResult.Cancel
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Modified = true;
    }
    protected static DataView dv = null;//declared at the Class Level
    protected static DataTable dtSearch = null;
    public static DataTable dtCrossTab { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtbox.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            dtSearch = dtCrossTab;//this is the original datatable
            dv = new DataView(dtSearch);//assigning the dtSearch to dv object
            dv.RowFilter = "NAME 4 LIKE '%" + txtbox.Text.ToUpper() + "%'";

        }
        else
        {
            dtSearch = null;
            dv = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whatis the `4` doing in filter?

Comment: Nothing, I tried to write Colomn 4 but it didnt work, since I am not using SQL I don't think this line will work but I don't know how to make it work without SQL (I really can't use SQL(LINQ))

Comment: ok. did you check the filterstring? It does look ok in code, though. And the very same code does work here. The columntype is string? Any formatting applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigned to the DataSource, you're assigning an entire data source to GridView.
I recommend you have a list or a collection where you have all the data. I have this example:

```
IEnumerable<Product> ListProduct = from Prod in LstProducts where Prod.Description.StartsWith(txtFind.Text) select Prod;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (var item in ListProduct)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.Id, item.Status, item.Description, tipo.Price);
        }
```

And filter the information in the column you want (Description) and using the filter you want (StartsWith), but for this you need to have a list of objects (LstProducts). I hope it has been helpful.

Edit. Your code now would look like

```
private void txtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    DataView DV = new DataView(datatable);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("ColumnX LIKE '%{0}%'", txtbox.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DV; 
 }
```

Where X is the number of the column you want to filter. If you want more control, I recommend you to change the names of the columns ID, name, description, etc.

Comment: This is LINQ, Why not use it?

Comment: I've seen your error. In this line ´DV.RowFilter = string.Format ( "Name LIKE '% {0}%'" txtbox.Text);´ the names of your columns are different, but we duvuelve no filter. Name changes the name of the column to filter.

Comment: I copied the rest of my code in the post, the part is at the bottom... what do you suggest exactly ?

Comment: Your code looks like this: DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtbox.Text); but how they create the columns of the GridView, they have a different name Column1, Column2, etc. Then you should look like this: DV.RowFilter = string.Format ("Column1 LIKE '% {0}%'" txtbox.Text);

Comment: Thanks richard but this is what I get now:  Warning 1 Field 'CsvFileTest.Form1.datatable' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Comment: I don't think I will be able to complete this... I would need another language or something to read and search CSV file with no SQL.

Comment: That mistake is when you declare this:
     protected static DataView dv = null; // Declared at the Class Level
     protected static DataTable dtSearch = null;
     public static DataTable dtCrossTab {get; set; }
At no time are you assigning values (dtSearch = dtCrossTab;) and yet assign, therefore, always have null values.

Comment: If you served something my help, response rate

Comment: My email is bbys@me.com, I'm in iMessage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103534/discussion-between-drew-salesse-and-richard).